# Youtube API - Switch between normal and brand accounts

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

On youtube.com, we can easily switch between channels by clicking on the user picture on the top right of the screen, then 'Switch Account'.

I would like to have a similar functionality in my app. I already made it possible to connect using any account (brand or normal), however I need for one login to retrieve data (login informations, profile picture, etc) about all brand channels.

I can of course ask the user to connect multiple time, and then store the informations that I need, but I would like to avoid that.

Is it possible to do that?

**Edited:**

I don't have any code for the moment, but by looking at the youtube api I'm not able to find any way to do this. The ideal should be to have something similar to the `/{user-id}/accounts` of Facebook's Graph API https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts&version=v3.1 which allow to see all pages accounts – Raphael just now   edit

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I don't have any code for the moment, but by looking at the youtube api I'm not able to find any way to do this. The ideal should be to have something similar to the `/{user-id}/accounts` of Facebook's Graph API https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts&version=v3.1 which allow to see all pages accounts